# Could one make a file in WinXP that is executable and unreadable at the same time?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

Is it possible to change the permission on a file so that other users could execute it, but they can't read or copy the file to another place.  I think you could do something like this on a Linux machine by using chmod +x and -r.  Could one do this in WinXP using the access control available?

Comment: Yes, you can, using NTFS file permissions. Gortok is right, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling the **Traverse Folder/Execute File** permission (need to go to Advanced display in the file security properties). At the same time disable read permission. I haven't confirmed this, but give it a go and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
As 20th Century Boy states, you can grant Traverse/Execute permissions under advanced permissions.

This can cause other problems for executing the program, that can cause it to crash, but it will attempt to run. Certain parts of the executable will be unavailable, such as its icon, compatibility information, etc, but it will still execute.  If the executable contains information that it needs to access while running, this can cause the application to become unstable.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be possible in Novell Netware, although these days I don't see an analog in NTFS file permissions.

I did just test --x permissions on a linux box and while it works with ELF binaries it's unlikely to work with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it's working for me.  I only see the file read+executable permission.  And when I set it to not readable, I can't execute anymore.  Will check some other combination of the other options in the advanced display.